# Populate a panda's dataframe column based on another column and dictionary value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a data frame that contain a column called DIAGNOSES. This DIAGNOSES column contain a list of 1 or multiple strings, starting with a Character.

I want to check the first character of every row in DIAGNOSES and grab its first char to look it up from a dictionary to populate DIAGNOSES_TYPE column with these values.

Minimal Example:

```
diagnoses = {'A': 'Arbitrary', 'B': 'Brutal', 'C': 'Cluster', 'D': 'Dropped'}

df = pd.DataFrame({'DIAGNOSES': [['A03'], ['A03', 'B23'], ['A30', 'B54', 'D65', 'C60']]})
```

```
              DIAGNOSES
0                 [A03]
1            [A03, B23]
2  [A30, B54, D65, C60]
```

A little visualization to clarify what I want to get, I want to get the df['DIAGNOSES_TYPES'] populated:

[image: Diagnoses Dataframe with desired column]

I approached it this way:

```py
def map_diagnose(df)
    for col in len(range(df)):
        for d in df['DIAGNOSIS']:
            for diag in d:
                if diag[0] in diagnoses_dict.keys():
                    df['DIAGNOSES_TYPES'] = diagnoses_dict.get(diag[0])
                df['DIAGNOSES_TYPES'] = ''
    return df
```

Comment: can you please include any code you've written in your question? a sample of the DataFrame would be useful too- you can paste the result of `df.head().to_dict()` into your question

Comment: could you include sample data and desired outcome? it's not clear what you exactly want

Comment: @DerekO I included it in the question.

Comment: @enke What I want is to populate a column called df['DIAGNOSES_TYPE'] from another existing column called df['DIAGNOSES'] where I would pick the first letter from the diagnoses look a dict and attach the value of a dict to the new column df['DIAGNOSES_TYPE']. I included some visualization. I am stuck at making it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `explode` "DIAGNOSES" column, get the first elements of each string using `str`, map `diagnoses` dictionary to get types, `groupby` the index and aggregate to a list:

```
df['DIAGNOSES_TYPE'] = df['DIAGNOSES'].explode().str[0].map(diagnoses).groupby(level=0).apply(list)
```

Output:

```
              DIAGNOSES                         DIAGNOSES_TYPE
0                 [A03]                            [Arbitrary]
1            [A03, B23]                    [Arbitrary, Brutal]
2  [A30, B54, D65, C60]  [Arbitrary, Brutal, Dropped, Cluster]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful to apply it all in one data-frame and it solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

use `explode`, `map` and `groupby`:

```
diagnoses = {'A': 'Arbitrary', 'B': 'Brutal', 'C': 'Cluster', 'D': 'Dropped'}
df1 = df.explode('DIAGNOSES')
df1['SD'] = df1['DIAGNOSES'].str.extract('(\D)')
df1['DIAGNOSES_TYPES'] = df1['SD'].map(diagnoses)
df1.groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

output:

```
    DIAGNOSES                SD             DIAGNOSES_TYPES
0   [A03]                    [A]            [Arbitrary]
1   [A03, B23]               [A, B]         [Arbitrary, Brutal]
2   [A30, B54, D65, C60]     [A, B, D, C]   [Arbitrary, Brutal, Dropped, Cluster]
```

Column 'SD' there is the first letter of each dagnoses used for mapping; you can `drop` this column if not needed

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me. The explode one is what I was missing. Much appreciated!